# Создание плагина для tinyMCE

Tags: php, tinymce, плагин, javascript

Решил создать расширение для текстового редактора и сразу начались проблемы, а именно:

редактор не видит папку с плагином или не хочет создавать его (никак не пойму)...

Что я делал:

1. Скопировал папку "example" с тестовым плагином
2. Переименовал ее в "diagramm"
3. Отредактировал `editor_plugin_src.js` ( [что внутри](http://pastebin.com/zDn1ezjb) )
4. Сделал сжатый вид кода и засунул его в `editor_plugin.js` ( [сайт для сжатия кода](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) )
5. Добавил загрузку плагина и кнопку в `lib.php`:

`'plugins' => "diagramm,...",
'theme_advanced_buttons3_add' => "table,diagramm,|,code,spellchecker",`

В итоге ни кнопки, ни плагина редактор не видит. Точно также подключил "example" - все отлично работает, хотя в "diagramm" я менял только названия плагина и команд. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы появилась кнопка нового плагина, необходимо, 1. в папке **\plugins\diagramm\img** переименовать **example.gif** в **diagramm.gif**; 2. в файле **\plugins\diagramm\editor_plugin.js** заменить все **example** на **diagramm** ну а **'plugins' => "diagramm,...",** и **'theme_advanced_buttons3_add' => "table,diagramm,** вы добавили

В итоге у меня получился вот такой editor_plugin.js

```
(function(){tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack("diagramm");tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.diagrammPlugin",{init:function(a,b){a.addCommand("mcediagramm",function(){a.windowManager.open({file:b+"/dialog.htm",width:320+parseInt(a.getLang("diagramm.delta_width",0)),height:120+parseInt(a.getLang("diagramm.delta_height",0)),inline:1},{plugin_url:b,some_custom_arg:"custom arg"})});a.addButton("diagramm",{title:"diagramm.desc",cmd:"mcediagramm",image:b+"/img/diagramm.gif"});a.onNodeChange.add(function(d,c,e){c.setActive("diagramm",e.nodeName=="IMG")})},createControl:function(b,a){return null},getInfo:function(){return{longname:"diagramm plugin",author:"Some author",authorurl:"http://tinymce.moxiecode.com",infourl:"http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/diagramm",version:"1.0"}}});tinymce.PluginManager.add("diagramm",tinymce.plugins.diagrammPlugin)})();
```

После этих манипуляций, у меня в редакторе появилась кнопка от плагина.

Ну, а чтобы заработал новый плагин - это уже другой вопрос :)